# How do I create a video DVD from vob files?

Tags: video, dvd, burning, brasero, k3b

I wanna burn a video DVD from existing .vob files that can be played in a home video player. I've burned one but it doesn't have sound. I tried with k3b (*New video DVD Project*) because Brasero doesn't have that option.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do it via command-line :

- Create a Folder called `dvd`.
- Create two folders in that directory called :

  1. VIDEO_TS subdirectory.
  2. AUDIO_TS subdirectory.
- copy the vob. and ifo. files to VIDEO_TS.

**Using mkisofs to create a DVD video ISO image**

> mkisofs -dvd-video -o dvdimage.iso
>   dvd/

Note: dvd/ is the directory that contains the VIDEO_TS subdirectory (and optionally an AUDIO_TS subdirectory).

The `mkisofs` command made an iso image `dvdimage.iso`and you can burn with brasero or k3b; the file name specified using the `-o` option. And the option `-dvd-video` was used to ensure that the ISO image has a DVD-Video compliant UDF file system. For more information, see: `mkisofs --help`

---

**Note : IMPORTANT READ CAREFULLY**

#### if you get this error :

```
INFO: no default video format, must explicitly specify NTSC or PAL
INFO: dvdauthor creating table of contents
INFO: Scanning DVD/VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_0.IFO
ERR: no video format specified for VMGM
```

it seems you now need the environment variable VIDEO_FORMAT set to `PAL` or `NTSC`, so try :

```
export VIDEO_FORMAT=NTSC or
export VIDEO_FORMAT=PAL
```

---

#### if you get this error :

```
genisoimage: No such file or directory. Failed to open VIDEO_TS.IFO
genisoimage: Can't open VMG info for 'dvd/'.
genisoimage: Unable to parse DVD-Video structures.
genisoimage: Could not find correct 'VIDEO_TS' directory.
genisoimage: Unable to make a DVD-Video image.
- VIDEO_TS subdirectory was not found on specified location
- VIDEO_TS has invalid contents
```

The way I read these messages, it's not a genisoimage error, it's about 
a missing in file named `VIDEO_TS.IFO` in which genisoimage expects to
find some data it calls "VMG info". VIDEO_TS.IFO is your information file for 
your menu (are configuration files with information about how to play exactly all 
video and audio content of DVD (including menus, subtitles, aspect ratio, languages etc.) , I'd guess it expects that file along with your VOB file, check your 
VIDEO_TS subdirectory or your directory sources to try to find that files.

- [The DVD (Video) file structure](http://dvdxcopy.afterdawn.com/thread_view.cfm/192714)

The IFO file type is primarily associated with 'DVD Info File'. An info file associated with a .VRO video file. The .VRO file contains the video stream and the .IFO file contains various scene and timing information. This is different from a .VOB file where that information is included in the file. Several manufacturers use .VRO/.IFO files. If present, the file VIDEO_TS.IFO consists of control and playback information for the entire DVD. VIDEO_TS.IFO is known as VMGI (The Video Manager Information file). This file is required to be present on a DVD-compliant disc.

---

`VIDEO_TS.BUP` is a backup of the `VIDEO_TS.IFO` check if you have it and make a copy.

#### Tyìcaly DVD Structure

[image]

Comment: This command line may fail: `genisoimage: No such file or directory. Failed to open VIDEO_TS.IFO
genisoimage: Can't open VMG info for 'dvd/'.
genisoimage: Unable to parse DVD-Video structures.
genisoimage: Could not find correct 'VIDEO_TS' directory.
genisoimage: Unable to make a DVD-Video image.
Possible reasons:
  - VIDEO_TS subdirectory was not found on specified location
  - VIDEO_TS has invalid contents
`

Answer (score 3):

In **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS** (and probably newer versions) `mkisofs` is just a symbolic link to `genisoimage` tool, but the command provided above retain same syntax:

```
genisoimage -dvd-video -o dvdimage.iso dvd/
```

This could be important if you want to read man pages to found more about `mkisofs` command, in that case just type:

```
man genisoimage
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Xfburn instead of Brasero to burn bootable .iso files.

Burnt own Demo CD and Promotonial own music CD couple of physical copies with Xfburn because of FLAC -file extension support. I don't know Brasero perhaps there's a .FLAC -support too, I suppose. It Have to have it?

Now I'm testing my own home video with this thread answer to make bootable .iso and watch if 4,1GB burnt DVD+R 4.7 Maxell disc works in my Standalone Samsung BR/DVD/CD 3d -disc player. It's old firmwared and newer is not becoming soon cause it was coming out of markets when I bought it for -60% discount from my supermarket Electronic department about 10 years ago. There's still DVD+/-R -support after CD-R support but not burnt BR-r:s.

It works fine as 100% with menus and everything I programmed as original "My Home Video for DVD Authorizing".